# Z-ordering of child views with respect to their parent

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

**Background**

In my app I have a lot of fragments that share the same static overlay. Each fragment can be resized dynamically (i.e. its weight may change) so I want the size of my overlay to be in sync with it. Therefore it makes sense to either make them siblings or, as it occurred to me, put one inside another. The first approach works fine but it implies introducing one extra `ViewGroup` which seems redundant (or does it not?). The latter is the one I'm having problems with.

**Problem**

Consider these two layouts.

Container `R.id.container` is where I put my fragment in runtime with `FragmentManager`.
Fragment `R.id.overlay` is my overlay.

The difference is which one is the parent.

*Layout A.*

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment class="com.example.OverlayFragment"
        android:id="@+id/overlay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

*Layout B.*

```
<fragment class="com.example.OverlayFragment"
    android:id="@+id/overlay"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</fragment>
```

In **both** cases my overlay ends up **below** container (by z-axis). That is, container keeps overlapping it regardless of its role in hierarchy.

What are the rules for defining views's z-order in situations like this? Is it just the order of their initialization? I couldn't google it out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html):

> When the system creates this activity layout, it instantiates each
>   fragment specified in the layout and calls the onCreateView() method
>   for each one, to retrieve each fragment's layout. The system inserts
>   the View returned by the fragment directly in place of the 
>   element.

So I think you should use something like this:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <fragment class="com.example.OverlayFragment"
        android:id="@+id/overlay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks, that's what I eventually did. Still, it's quite unclear to me what is meant by "directly in place of the element" when the element serves as a view group.

Comment: the system replaces the view that you return inside `onCreateView` instead of `fragment`tag in xml file. for example if the root view of your fragment is linearlayout then it likes you remove the fragment tag in xml file and then add linearlayout. it is like `@include` in layouts.

Comment: I understand that. But what if a `fragment` has nested views, as in Layout B? Do those views get appended to the `LinearLayout` returned by `onCreateView()`?

Comment: yes they do. I think they call `addView` of `the viewgroup` of the fragment. Also make sure your fragment support nested fragments.